how to use aws oidc trusted entity setup for github actions to restrict the permissions to ones triggered by pull_requests
I am trying to setup an trusted entity for aws oidc setup which restricts to pull requests.
What should the value be for "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub" ?
repo:<orgName/repoName>:pull_request still gives me the error: Could not assume role with OIDC: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
repo:<orgName/repoName>:pull_request
I was expecting this to allow the pull request builds to be trusted by the oidc role but it still cannot assume the role from a job triggered by pull_requests
